# Why is $\mathcal{E}(X)=\mathcal{E}(X,X^*)$?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

According to a course about $\sigma$-agebras in infinite dimensional space they said that it is easy to see that :

$$\mathcal{E}(X)=\mathcal{E}(X,X^*)$$

where:

- $X$ is separable real Banach space.
- $\mathcal{E}(X)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylindrical sets, i.e., the sets of the form
  $$
  C=\{x\in X:\ (f_1(x),...,f_n(x))\in C_0\}
  $$
  where $f_1,...,f_n\in X^*$ and $C_0\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$
- $\mathcal{E}(X,X^*)$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X^*$ on $X$ i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that all the functions $f\in X^*$ are measurable.

**Question:**

How did they prove such equality which seems to me not obvious ?!

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that every $x^* \in X^*$ is $\def\EX{\mathcal E(X)}\def\EXX{\mathcal E(X,X^*)}$ $\EX$-measurable, as for $C_0 \in \def\B{\operatorname{Bor}}\B\def\R{\mathbf R}(\R)$ we have 
$$ x^{*-1}[C] = \{x \in X: x^*(x) \in C_0 \}\in \EX $$
Hence $\EXX \subseteq \EX$. On the other hand, let $n \in \mathbf N$, $x_i^* \in X^*$ and $B_i \in\B(\R)$ for $1 \le i \le n$. We have 
$$ \left\{x \in X : (x_1^*,\ldots, x_n^*)(x) \in \prod_i B_i \right\} = \bigcap_{i} x_i^{*-1}[B_i]  \in \EXX$$
As the sets of the form $\prod_i B_i$ generate $\B(\R^n)$, it follows that 
$$ \{x \in X : (x_1^*, \ldots, x_n^*)(x) \in C \} \in \EXX $$
for every $C \in \B(\R^n)$. Hence $\EX \subseteq \EXX$.